# Who Am I? I am not sure myself

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> I am a number, I've a number of names.
>   My name is in itself.
>   I am hiding in plain sight.
>   I am damned if I don't and damned if I do.
>   (Perhaps this riddle would be better if it rhymed...)

**Update**:

"I am a number" is not meant to be taken literally. The answer is not a number.

Additional clues:

> I am a master of many, choosing to become a slave.
>   My spirit belongs to another, my face to another still.

Comment: Is the last line part of the riddle?

Comment: @MarioGarcia Yes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are

> Jean Valjean - 24601

I am a number, I've a number of names.

> 24601, Mayor of town, Jean Valjean

My name is in itself.

> Jean val**jean**

I am hiding in plain sight.

> He's a Mayor, he's known by everyone in town yet still manages to hide

I am damned if I don't and damned if I do.

> Quoting from "Who am I" which is a song from musical Les Misérables: "If I speak, I am condemned. If I stay silent, I am damned!"

Comment: That's a good answer, but not the droid I'm looking for :) Also, the "rhyme" section is sorta part of the riddle, and so is the "I'm not sure myself" in the title.

Comment: @YehudaShapira Edited.

Comment: +1 In hindsight it makes perfect sense but safe to say I would have never guessed this.

Answer (score 13):

Are you

> The number 2

I am a number, I've a number of names.

> 2 is also known as couple, pair, duo.

My name is in itself.

> Two contains 't and o'. to.

I am hiding in plain sight.

> We have two eyes which we use to see, but we don't see our two eyes.

I am damned if I don't and damned if I do.

> Two choices.

(Perhaps this riddle would be better if it rhymed...)

> Couplets are a common form of rhyme consisting of two line endings in sequence.

Comment: This is a really good answer, too. I realized now that my riddle is misleading, and updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Are you

> "I"?

I am a number, I've a number of names.

> "I" is also the roman numeral of 1.

My name is in itself.

> The letter "i" is in the word, "itself."

I am hiding in plain sight.

> The letter "i" is also in the words "plain" and "sight."

I am damned if I don't and damned if I do.

> You are "I," either way.

(Perhaps this riddle would be better if it rhymed...)

> A little stumped on how this one would fit, except that "i" is in riddle, but only the "i" sound is in "rhymed" - and the sounds of the words are one of the elements of rhyme.

Comment: I quite like this answer. It took a more literal approach. $(+1)$

Answer (score 4):

You are

> A mythological little person

I am a number, I've a number of names.

> Goes by many names. Gnome, Dwarf, Munchkins etc

My name is in itself.

> My name in in 'itself' - **elf**

I am hiding in plain sight

> A common trope, eg. The Hobbit, The Elf and the Shoemaker

I am damned if I don't and damned if I do.

> Not a race of Humans so no matter what they have no otherworldly salvation

(Perhaps this riddle would be better if it rhymed...)

> Another Elf helper trope. eg. Oompa Loompas

Answer (score 3):

You are

> The word "in"

My name is in itself:

Rather, you are "In", itself

I am hiding in plain sight:

The word "in" is in the sentence as well as hiding at the end of the word "plain".

I am damned if I don't and damned if I do:

As in, are you in or are you out.

Comment: I've added spoilers. Don't do that again please.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Good answer! c:

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Spoilers are not required.

Comment: @Desouvi Yes they are! There have been posts removed in the past for no spoilers! It is a rule!

Answer (score 1):

You are

> Magic, a number, a trick

Hiding in plain sight

> Slight of hand, misdirection, illusion

Master of many, choosing to be a slave

> Magic takes practice, you need to master it to be good, yet it's a tool to be used

Although there's a correct answer chosen already, I thought my answer still fits.